# EntityManagerFactory is null

Tags: hibernate, jax-rs, wildfly, resteasy

I've been working on a RESTEasy project and cant seem to inject entityManager.

I have wildfly and mysql.

This is my datasource which works when I test the connection with Wildfly

```
Name: Test  
JNDI: java:/Test
Driver: mysql-connector-java-5.1.33.jar_com.mysql.jdbc.Driver_5_1
```

This is my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="Test" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:/Test</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
             <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
             <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
             <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
           <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

this is where I want to use the entityManagerFactory.

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.SecurityContext;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceUnit;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
@Path("/test")
public class TestApi  {
@PersistenceUnit(unitName = "Test")
private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

@GET
@Path("/")
public Response Action(@Context SecurityContext securityContext)
throws NotFoundException {
        Action action = new Action();
        action.setGameId(1234);
        action.setScore(90);
        action.setUserId(321);
        action.setType("test");
        em.persist(action);
}
```

I tried to the application-managed approach and had it working but I really wanted it to be container-managed and cant make it to work. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: no, there are no errors

Comment: That should be working. How are you deploying your application?

Comment: now that you mentioned deployment, I have had this error before. then I manually removed the .ResteasyJackson2Provider jar and it went away

`loader constraint violation: when resolving overridden method "org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jackson.ResteasyJackson2Provider$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.enable(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser$Feature;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/base/ProviderBase;`

Comment: Are you by chance including Jackson in your deployment? Maybe Hibernate as well?

Comment: yes I have both Jackson and Hibernate

Comment: Try excluding those from your deployment as they should be provided by the server.